# Error: derefferencing out of bounds pointer

Tags: c

Given the below code, I get the following error at runtime

> FATAL RUN-TIME ERROR: line 21, col 11, thread id 0x00002068:
>   Dereference of out-of-bounds pointer: 1 bytes (1 elements) past end of
>   array.

What am I doing wrong here? I create a 2D char array and initialize all elements to 'x'. Then I attempt to print all elements by using the pointer logic. It prints the characters to standard IO but then throws the runtime error. I don't see where the out of bounds is occurring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define EDGE 10

int main(void){

    char fabric[EDGE][EDGE];
    char *cell = fabric;
    int totalCells = EDGE*EDGE;

    for(int i = 0; i < totalCells; ++i){    
            *(cell + i) = 'x';
    }

    cell = fabric; //set cell to point back to first element

    while(*cell){                  //while there is content at address, print content
        printf("%c", *cell);
        ++cell;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The array does not store a string. So this condition while(*cell) is invalid.

Comment: `char *cell = fabric;` is an error, if you do not see an error message then adjust your compiler settings until you do.

Comment: `while(*cell) //while there is content at address` The comment is wrong. It should be `// while cell points to a non-zero byte`. If there are no zero bytes in `fabric`, you go out of bounds.

Comment: Don't use `*(cell + i) = ...` when `cell[i] = ...` is equivalent and way easier to read. In your case, though, you have a *two dimensional array* so you should reference `fabric[i][j]`.

Comment: Ok, your comments make sense. I guess I forgot that using this method is for strings since there is a null terminating character on those. I changed it to be a for loop. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman, for the size that fabric will end up being (edge will become 1000), I need to use pointers and the heap, using array notation will cause stack overflow.

Comment: If array notation causes a stack overflow you're doing it wrong from an algorithmic perspective. You do not need to use a pointer. A pointer only complicates things. 1000 entries is trivial.

Comment: For the kind of compiler whose runtime system can generate this diagnostic, it is pretty risky to assume you can address an array[][] as though it is one big array[] wad.  You'd be likely to overwrite intentional guard space that the diagnostic uses to detect an overrun.  Be sure to tag questions about this compiler with its name, like [labwindows]

Comment: If you really don't care about the 2D array, as you're not even using it directly in the first place, just `malloc()` a structure of the correct size and use that. Don't *assume* that you can stomp around in the 2D array as if it's one big linear chunk of memory. It may not be. You'll often encounter `char**` type structures where you need to re-reference pointers in the middle, even if superficially they look like `x[i][j]` when used. The compiler can and will hide a lot of implementation details.

Comment: I believe LabWindows uses the Clang compiler. Is that a less powerful compiler than GCC? Also, what I'm trying to do here is create a giant 'fabric' where the elements of a data set occupy certain squares within this big array. They will have parameters that specify coordinates and how many spaces they occupy. Do I even need the fabric? Maybe it's just best to create an array of structures, with each structure defining its space, then I can see where overlaps occur by searching the array of structs to locate common elements. Thoughts?

Comment: @tadman how do you feel about the above?

Comment: Clang is in many ways better than GCC, though it is newer and doesn't support as many architectures, though that's largely an academic issue in most cases. Both are very capable compilers. You need to figure out the algorithm you're using here, then implement that, as opposed to just throwing code at the wall. As a note, if you know a scripting language like Python, Ruby or even JavaScript you can often quickly prototype your algorithm, then port that to C++ when you get a handle on the approach you're using.

Comment: I think what Hans was saying is that the runtime error you got there is pretty specific, so if you're going balls to the wall here, it might help to know what you're using. Highly recommend what tadman said about prototyping in python. If you have access to matlab/mathematica/maple, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly recommend you just malloc/memset your structure instead of doing the hacky pointer thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EDGE        ( 10 )
#define TOTAL_CELLS ( EDGE * EDGE )

int main()
{
    int i;
    char * fabric = malloc(TOTAL_CELLS);
    memset(fabric,'x',TOTAL_CELLS);


    for(i=0; i<TOTAL_CELLS; i++){
        printf("%c",fabric[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you still want to reference the 2D array-like structure (`fabric[i][j]`), you can do it in a 1D array just as easily (`fabric[i*EDGE+j]`), and its easier to manipulate that linear memory block.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the array does not contain a string. So this condition

```
while(*cell){
```

results in undefined behaviour.

Also you have to cast pointers in the declaration and in the statement

```
char *cell = ( char * )fabric;

cell = ( char * )fabric;
```

because there is no implicit conversion from the type `char ( * )[EDGE]` to the type `char *`.

Comment: @tadman  This declaration char *cell = &fabric; is totally incorrect.